# Our OAuth2 implemention has security flaws

Tags: java, angularjs, security, oauth-2.0

I logged in as Scott who only has read permission. The oauth2 server(JAVA based) gave me a token. Then I asked my teammate to send me his non-expired token. I updated my Angular application and hardcoded the token that was given to me. I tried to make changes to the api and I was able to make some change.

How can backend api prevent this?

Comment: **Then I asked my teammate to send me his non-expired token**. This is like I asked my friend his Gmail password, and now I have access to his gmail account. So Gmail has security flaw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've successfully implemented a [session hijack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack). This happens because sessions are based on tokens stored in the web page or cookies rather than IP addresses or something. This makes sense because IP addresses can be spoofed while a cryptographically secure session token is practically impossible to spoof.

While you could add strategies to make this more difficult (eg: some kind of hardware token that is involved in cryptographically signing every message), why do you feel you need to? All but the most secure sites rely on this mechanism.

Comment: Thank you Neil Smithline. Just wondering why the post got downvoted. Is it because it didn't have a code?

Comment: Based on the comment to your question, I think people voted it down because they felt it had an obvious answer. Perhaps if you would have made the question "I'm confused about our OAUTH2 implementation's security" it would have been better accepted? Can't be sure.

Comment: Oh. https://security.stackechange.com would have been another option for this question though I don't think that stackoverflow is a bad choice.

Comment: Got it. I wasn't aware of it. Thank you!